# Rest API java spring - Upload text and pdf to PostgreSQL database (postman - form data)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, postman

I am making a REST API in Java spring. I want to make a post request in postman and upload some text and  a pdf file to my postgreSQL database. The connection works. I tested it with another endpoint. I tried alot of things but none of them works.

I heard you can do this with postman - Form data.

What I tried:
added this to the @PostMapping() --> No success

```
consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE
```

In postman:
added `Content-type : application/json`
and`Content-type : multipart/form-data`

Both of them with no success :(...

Below my restcontroller

```java
@RestController
public class SheetMusicController {

    @Autowired
    SheetMusicRepository sheetMusicRepository;

    @GetMapping("/sheetmusic")
    public List<SheetMusic> index(){
        return sheetMusicRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/sheetmusic")
    public SheetMusic create(@RequestBody Map<String,String> body){
        String title = body.get("title");
        byte[] pdf = "".getBytes();

        SheetMusic sheetMusic = new SheetMusic(title,"","","",pdf);
        return sheetMusic;
    }
}
```

And a picture of postman
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41hBG.png)

I don't see what I do wrong. I hope you guys can help me out!

Greetings,

Comment: `@RequestBody` looks for body of the Post request made on `/sheetmusic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a `multipart form-data` request:

**First**, you need to add to maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Second**, you need to add this `Bean` configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

**Finally**, your `Post` method should be like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/sheetmusic")
public SheetMusic create(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("title") String title) {
    // Your business
}
```

**NOTE:** for the `Postman` you just need to select the body type `form-data` and the Content-Type will be set automatically.

Comment: Hi First of all, thank you for your clear comment!! It works, but now I have 1 small other problem. What value should the column have for the file name? At the moment I have bytea and in Java I have String.

Comment: First, if this solution solves the mentioned problem you need need to mark it as the right answer.
To answer your question, you mean by file name field the field with name 'title'?

Comment: I mean the column name in the database, Should it be a var ? or a bytea? or a integer

Comment: You mean in the database table or in your entity class?

Comment: Both actually :)

Comment: In your entity class, you can assign the file data to byte[] type annotated by @Lob, like this:
    \@Lob
    private byte[] data;

Comment: see this if you want: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-jpa-hibernate-mysql-database-example/

Comment: Hmm I did that, I am getting an internal server error status 500. could not extract ResultSet

Comment: When you did exactly get this exception?

Comment: Hmm somehow I need to convert MultipartFile to a byte[] right?

Comment: Of course and it's simple you just need to call getBytes() method of a MultipartFile.

Comment: yeah I did convert it, but still internal server error 500

Comment: byte [] byteArr= file.getBytes();

Comment: yes :(. I'm checking if I have autogenered key on the id

Comment: If the problem is not related to this issue you can ask a new question with the required details.

Comment: Yea that's a good idea. I will try it first myself and then post it if I don't know how to do it. Thank you by the way. you helped me out alot! I couldn't figure it out myself :).

Answer (score 0):

Change @Postmapping to @Requestmapping. It should work then.